# RoR ActiveRecord How to query scopes + has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm facing a common problem with Ruby on Rails. I do have a nested `has_many` relations
Accounts > has_many > Sites > has_many > Pages > has_many > Blocks

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  enum status: [:enabled, :disabled, :archived, :deleted]
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sites
  enum status: [:enabled, :disabled, :archived, :deleted]
end
```

In the example how can I query all the enabled sites? I can do `Site.enabled` to use the scope. I also can use `Account.enabled`. But I cannot use `Account.enabled.sites` because `enabled` scope returns an active_relation. Is there a clean way to achieve that in Rails?

My current workaround is `Account.enabled.each(&:sites)`, but now it's an array and not an active_relation! so doing `Account.enabled.each(&:sites).enabled` doesn't filter up properly.

I look through the rails api docs searching for a `each` which preserve the active_relation class instead of returning an array.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no built in way to do what you want. I'd do it from the `Site` side by creating a scope within `Site` that returned only those with associated `enabled` `Account`s:

### Site

```rb
  scope :with_enabled_account, -> { joins(:account).merge Account.enabled }
```